# Laravel Request File Change

Tags: php, laravel, request

I have an issue for Request Laravel when i'm uploading file with key 'siup', the Request data shown like this:

```
"_token" => "Ab9zfuQn0rb0exCx7IdMcnAxQWi4iqWcfcDy319B"
"_method" => "PUT"
"first_name" => "first"
"last_name" => "aaa"
"email" => "black.y_+ta@email.com"
"province" => "11"
"city_id" => "38"
"address" => "asdasd"
"phone" => "1234567890"
"company_type" => "koperasi"
"company_name" => "qqq"
"company_address" => "qqq"
"pic" => "qqqa"
"position" => "qqq"
"siup" => UploadedFile {#30 ▶}
```

i want to do this to the request response

```
$request->merge(['siup'=>$myVar]);
```

but the key siup did not change. i want to change the siup value to insert it to database with laravel eloquent update.

Answer (score 2):

The request data exposed by the `Request` object comes from two different sources: the query data and the files. When you dump the contents of the request data, it merges these two sources together and that is your output.

When you use the `merge()`, `replace()`, etc. methods, it is only manipulating the query data. Therefore, even though you're attempting to overwrite the `siup` data, you're actually only changing the `siup` key in the query data. The `siup` key in the files data is not touched. When you dump the contents of the request data again, the `siup` files data overwrites your `siup` query data.

You will save yourself a lot of trouble if you just get your data as an array, and then just use the array as needed. This is a lot safer and easier than trying to manipulate the `Request` object, and is probably a lot more along the lines of what you should be doing anyway.

Something like:

```
$data = $request->except('siup');
$data['siup'] = $myVar;

// now use your data array
MyModel::create($data);
```

Comment: so i can't remove siup key on my request variable?

Comment: @patricus THANK YOU !!! I spent godamn hours trying to figure out why the replace on my uploaded file didn't work, now i'm doing a dirty thing by replacing request files with $request->files->replace(array('file1'->file1)), but it works ! (in my case it's a single file upload every time)

Comment: Somehow $this->validate($request, $rules) has an unchanged $request for the file part again...